# get Files from Mongo GridFS in bash Script

Tags: bash, mongodb, gridfs

Is it in bash script possible to get files, based on a ObjectID, which are stored on in a Mongo GridFS databse.

With the following command I can get the binairy data from the chunks.

```
OBJECTID=ObjectId("5608dd301a8014a568f71921");

mongo localhost:27020/Test_files --eval 'db.fs.chunks.find({"files_id":'${OBJECTID}'},{"data":1,"_id":0}).limit(1).forEach(printjson)';
```

But I want to have the binairy data stored in a text file on my filesystem, based on the OBJECTID.
Is this possible?

Comment: We could question that if it is possible for you to do this then why are you using GridFS in the first place? The data is clearly less than the 16MB BSON limit for you to be able to get a single document from `fs.chunks` so if it is "text" then you should have just stored it as "text" in a single document property. The returned data from the shell is Base64 encoded, so look for Base64 to binary in JavaScript to get the job done.

Comment: That was a possible solluction, but in the futher the files get bigger than 16MB.  So there for it is not possible to select it with the collection fs.chunks.  In PHP there is a GRIDFS driver to get the data.  (->getbytes).

But how do I do this in bash_script?